# What is the one element equivalence of a SPSC lock-free queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, message-queue

I know that such structure can be implemented using a `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue` with buffer size `1`:

```
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<T, boost::lockfree::capacity<1>>
```

but this seems very inelegant. What would be a better way to do it? A `std::optional<T>` coupled with a mutex would probably work but it is better to be lockfree.

Comment: It is not simply "better to be lockfree". Especially not frequently when there's not bursty workload. Lockfree often comes down to "trade power usage for latency". And complexity, of course.